# Pearson's chi-square statistic for goodness-of-fit in generalized linear models

Tags: generalized-linear-model

To test the goodness-of-fit in generalized linear models with parameter $\beta$, from [a note](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~xianghua/8452/note/05GEE.pdf)

> Another measure of discrepancy is the generalized Pearson’s chi-square statistic
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{(y_i − \hat{μ_i})^2}{V(\hat{μ_i})}$$

where $\hat{μ_i} := μ_i(\hat{\beta})$, $\mu_i$ is the mean of $Y_i$ under $x_i$, and $V$ is the variance function of the mean.

But according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test), the Pearson’s chi-square statistic seems to be
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{(y_i − \hat{μ_i})^2}{\hat{μ_i}}$$
So why are these two different? Thanks!

Comment: More than one thing can have a chi-square distribution. The thing you link to is not exactly the more general thing you're asking abut at the start, though *in the particular case of multinomial or Poisson $y$* and under the right conditioning, they will end up the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual expression is goodness of fit (edited in your question). (Strictly, chi-square is a measure of badness of fit as it increases with what R.A. Fisher called the discrepancy between observed and fitted, but "badness of fit" is much rarer as a term, although sometimes used by Joseph B. Kruskal.)

You have answered your own question if you look carefully. The generalized definition has variance of fitted as denominator: whenever variance of fit is equal to mean fit, the definitions coincide, which corresponds to Poisson variation.

The standard idea, which is really important, is that chi-square statistics are the sum of terms which each have the flavour (value $-$ mean)$^2$/variance or [(value $-$ mean) / SD]$^2$.

Comment: Thanks! "Whenever variance of fit is equal to mean fit, the definitions coincide, which corresponds to Poisson variation." What do "variance of fit" and "mean fit" mean? Why do the two definitions coincide, and correspond to Poisson variation?

Comment: You ask questions like this and you want explanations of variance and mean??? Fit $=$ fitted $=$ expected, if that's the obstacle in your way.

Comment: Does "variance of fit" mean the first definition which has variance in the denominator, and does "mean of fit" mean the second definition which has mean in the denominator? Why "whenever variance of fit is equal to mean fit, the definitions coincide" and why do they "corresponds to Poisson variation"?

Comment: " chi-square statistics are the sum of terms which each have the flavour $(value − mean)^2/variance$ or $[(value − mean) / SD]^2$." In Wikipedia, the chi square statistic is $(value − mean)^2/SD$ instead

Comment: That's not a precise reference, but it sounds like more evidence for the unreliability of Wikipedia, as if any were needed.

Answer (score -1):

The question can be answered much more easily. See the numerator. It is a squared value (dimension or Power as two). To generate statistics, the denominator must have dimension (power) as two. The statistics is ratio with variance.
Else, if we go with definition with mean as denominator, our statistics will increase indefinitely.

Comment: I fail to see how this constitutes an answer. This is a comment at best.