# Is the generalized Pearson’s chi-square statistic a pseudo $R^2$?

Tags: regression, residuals

Is [the generalized Pearson's chi-square statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62964/pearsons-chi-square-statistic-for-goodness-of-fit-in-generalized-linear-models) viewed as [a pseudo $R^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Pseudo-R2s)? I think yes, because a pseudo $R^2$ is a generalization of the form of $R^2$, and the generalized Pearson's chi-square statistic has a form with the residuals in $R^2$ in its numerators. But I am not sure. Thanks.

Comment: Can't be - R^2 gets bigger when the fit is better. chi-square gets bigger when the fit is worse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pseudo $R^2$ typically tries to maintain the property that it has a value between 0 and 1. A chi-square statistic does not have that property, as it is supposed to follow a chi-square distribution when the null hypothesis is true, so it would range between 0 and $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have the definition of  pseudo $R^2$?

Comment: A pseudo $R^2$ is any measure that its authors or its users think is not $R^2$ but is presented as, or considered as, similar in role to $R^2$. The term can be positive, neutral, or pejorative and is, for the most part, used loosely or broadly with no pretentions of rigour, exact inclusivity or exact exclusivity. (I am reminded obliquely of the definition that "soil" is anything so designated by a competent authority.)